# How to find time duration of tracert command using wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, traceroute

I tried to execute a tracert command in cmd in Windows 10, specifically, tracert www.ieee.org.

In the same time, I captured the packets with wireshark.

How can I find the time duration of my tracert command?

I guess the tracert starts with this line in wireshark: 
Standard query 0xb49e A www.ieee.org

But I am not sure when tracert ends and with which packet.

Also, while the tracert command is executed, there are other packets, from other apps in my computer that are obviously unrelated to the tracert, that interfere with the packets that tracert sends. Does those unrelated packets affect the time duration of tracert? How should I calculate the time of tracert command in wireshark?

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, I have no idea about networking.

Comment: The running duration of a host command is a host issue, pretty much off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the Wireshark display to only show ICMP packets to the target host.

Put this in the filter window:

```
icmp
```

Or, you can use

```
ip.addr==1.2.3.4  (target IP)
```

Comment: Part B of my exercise asks what protocols where used.
I know tracert uses icmp packets but there are also dns packets (ie Standard query 0xb49e A www.ieee.org, this is the info of the first packet, which is a dns packet, that is captured after the tracert command).

Comment: DNS is not part of traceroute, but you can try icmp || domain